# Print Web Server Crystal Report into user's Printer

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have web application and i am using SAP Crystal report with VS 2010.
I am using this method to print crystal report.

```
Report.PrintToPrinter(1, false,0,0)
```

It's working on my development machine but when i moved this to server. it's not printing and showing **NO Default Printer Set**. I am using VPS as server and installed crystal report too.
How do i get the print on user's client machine.

**Update :-**

All user's machine has different printer so i can't all in my server. I need a solution that will work all user's printer.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke method "Report.PrintToPrinter" it looks for printer which directly configured on server where your application deployed, not know any thing about your client machine connected printer.

You can give print command by print dialog where your client machine printer will be listed.

Comment: Printer install on development machine but not in server

Comment: yes same I Understand .. if you have deployed your application in server (other machine) and printer configured in your development machine (Client machine) now you try to give print command by using "Report.PrintToPrinter" method, it will look printer to send print which configured in server machine not on client.

Comment: If you have full access of your server configure one printer in server and try that command it surely send print on printer that you have configured.

Answer (score 0):

The specific printer must installed on sever machine then only it will take the printer , Other wise it shown warring "No Default Printer"